# JOIN EXPRESSION NOT SUPPORTED with 3 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm working with MS Access, trying to join 3 tables together. But i'm getting message "JOIN EXPRESSION NOT SUPPORTED.".
  Basically I want to join just 2 tables which are A_01HWeekEHCalendar and A00_Plant. A00_Plant requires 3 column to join; Plant_Product, Plant_Code, and Plant_Name. Plant_Product, Plant_Code is ok, but there is no column to match Plant_Product. so I have to add A_ProductGroup
  I'm not sure if it can't be done in one Query or it's error from my SYNTAX. or there will be another way to do that without separate Queries.
  I also add a picture of what I want and try to run and get error.

Thanks.

[image]

```
SELECT 
A_01HWeekEHCalendar.RunNo_H, 
A_01HWeekEHCalendar.Audit_Week, 
A_01HWeekEHCalendar.CurrentYear, 
A_01HWeekEHCalendar.CurrentWeek, 
A_01HWeekEHCalendar.TTSMonth, 
A_01HWeekEHCalendar.Audit_Plant, 
A_01HWeekEHCalendar.Audit_plantname, 
A_01HWeekEHCalendar.Audit_Qacode, 
A_01HWeekEHCalendar.Audit_Qaname, 
A_01HWeekEHCalendar.Audit_Product, 
A00_Plant.HCA_StartDate


FROM 
(A_01HWeekEHCalendar LEFT JOIN A_ProductGroup
ON A_01HWeekEHCalendar.Audit_Product = A_ProductGroup.R_Code) 
LEFT JOIN A00_Plant 
ON A_01HWeekEHCalendar.Audit_plantname = A00_Plant.Plant_Name 
AND A_01HWeekEHCalendar.Audit_Plant = A00_Plant.Plant_Code 
AND A_ProductGroup.R_Code = A00_Plant.Plant_Product;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the exact query above gives this error?  It looks correct to me.  The only thing I can imagine which might be causing problems is your total lacks of aliases.  But, aliases should be optional, I think.

Comment: Is it local data or linked data?

Comment: According to this: [link]( 
  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/15c36745-f7a4-4926-9687-7161e5894468/join-expression-not-supported-error-caused-by-unbracketed-join-expression-comprising-string?forum=accessdev)
it might be some missing brackets around the JOIN expressions.

But: in your example you join `A_01HWeekEHCalendar.Audit_Product = A_ProductGroup.R_Code` and in the next join `A_ProductGroup.R_Code = A00_Plant.Plant_Product` Which means you could just join `A_01HWeekEHCalendar.Audit_Product = A00_Plant.Plant_Product` and you don't need to use the third table.

Comment: @BData thanks. it's local data.

Comment: @JanB A_01HWeekEHCalendar.Audit_Product and A00_Plant.Plant_Product are not matching to each other. i have to add  A_ProductGroup  and that cause the problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think so. but if i change LEFT JOIN  to INNER JOIN for both of them, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are lucky because you want only one column.  You can work around this problem using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT . . .,
       (SELECT TOP (1) A00_Plant.HCA_StartDate
        FROM A00_Plant
        WHERE A_01HWeekEHCalendar.Audit_plantname = A00_Plant.Plant_Name 
 AND
              A_01HWeekEHCalendar.Audit_Plant = A00_Plant.Plant_Code AND 
              A_ProductGroup.R_Code = A00_Plant.Plant_Product
       ) as HCA_StartDate
FROM A_01HWeekEHCalendar LEFT JOIN
     A_ProductGroup
     ON A_01HWeekEHCalendar.Audit_Product = A_ProductGroup.R_Code ;
```